# How to remove rows acording to another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have two data frames like these:

```
set.seed(123)

a<-data.frame(x=rep(letters[1:3], each=3),
      y=sample(1:3, 9, T)) 

b<-data.frame(x=c("a", "b", "b"),
      y=c(3, 3, 1))
```

How can I remove the records in a by b? Such an outcome like this:

```
1 a 1
3 a 2
4 b 3
7 c 2
8 c 3
9 c 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a[!paste(a$x, a$y) %in% paste(b$x, b$y), ]

##   x y
## 1 a 1
## 3 a 2
## 7 c 2
## 8 c 3
## 9 c 2
```